# How does OCaml GC decide which block in minor heap is live or not

Tags: garbage-collection, ocaml

[Chapter 21, Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/understanding-the-garbage-collector.html#the-fast-minor-heap), it says:

> The minor heap is where most of your short-lived values are held. It
>   consists of one contiguous chunk of virtual memory containing a
>   sequence of OCaml blocks. If there is space, allocating a new block is
>   a fast, constant-time operation that requires just a couple of CPU
>   instructions.
>
> **To garbage-collect the minor heap, OCaml uses copying collection to move all live blocks in the minor heap to the major heap**. This takes
>   work proportional to the number of live blocks in the minor heap,
>   which is typically small according to the generational hypothesis. The
>   minor collection stops the world (that it, halts the application)
>   while it runs, which is why it's so important that it complete quickly
>   to let the application resume running with minimal interruption.

I understand that as it says clearly, in minor heap, live memory go to major heap.

However, how the gc decide live memory in minor heap?

Is it the same *mark and sweep* process which is for major heap?

Basically, during gc for **major** heap, it starts some roots in stack, and anything can be reached are live.

If gc for **minor** is also this case, how does OCaml quickly know which roots lead to minor heap memory, or quickly know which roots lead to major memory?

---

My confusion is actually that if OCaml does the same gc operations on minor as on major, how can OCaml distinguish? If it both starts from the stack, how can the GC goes to collect only on minor, not involving major?

---

**edit**

let's assume the minor heap size is only 4KB. Here is some code:

```
let f = 
  let a1 = Array.make (4 * 1024) 1 in
  let a2 = Array.make (4 * 1024) 2 in
  let a3 = Array.make (4 * 1024) 3 in
  ...
```

In the above code

1. `a1`'s address will be put onto stack and the real array will be in minor heap. the stack look like `[a1]`.
2. `a2` is being created. It finds out minor heap is full, so it will do minor gc. gc has a look at the stack, and so follows a1 and decide a1 is live and then `a1's array` will be copied to major heap and a1's pointer is changed to the new address in major? the stack now looks like `[a2;a1]`.
3. `a3` is being created. Just like 2, it has to do a minor gc. Will gc go through both a2 and a1? especially a1, even though a1 is in major?

Comment: You should read Wilson's http://www3.nd.edu/~dthain/courses/cse40243/spring2006/gc-survey.pdf . There is no point in figuring it out out of StackOverflow questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are relatively few pointers from the major heap to the minor heap because the values in the major heap are older. If OCaml was purely functional, there wouldn't be any pointer from major to minor heap.

In fact OCaml is not purely functional, and an old value in the major heap can be updated with pointers to new values in the minor heap. Any such write goes through a *write barrier* that records the major heap value as a root from the point of view of the next minor heap collection. The rest of the major heap does not need to be scanned for a minor collection.

Advance to section “Intergenerational Pointers” in [the book your are currently reading](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/understanding-the-garbage-collector.html) for a quick overview of the write barrier implementation.

About your example:

Yes, the GC visits the stack to determine what minor heap values must be preserved, but at point 3, when the GC sees that the pointer in the stack that points to `a1` points outside the minor heap, it can ignore it and immediately continue on to `a2`. All the references from major heap to minor heap have been collected in a *reference table* by the write barrier. No other locations in the major heap need to be visited, not even those that are referred to in the stack.

> Will gc go through both a2 and a1?

No, only `a2`. There is no reason to visit `a1` as it is outside the minor heap, and thus cannot point into the minor heap, unless it has been modified in which case it will be separately registered in the reference table.

Comment: `There is no reason to visit a1 as it is outside the minor heap` How can OCaml know `a1` is outside of minor? Does OCaml runtime keep such a table?

Comment: @JacksonTale How would you test if a block is in the minor heap, if you thought about it for two minutes?

Comment: to see whether the `a1`'s address is in the range of minor heap?

Comment: @JacksonTale Bingo. http://sourcecodebrowser.com/ocaml/3.10.2/minor__gc_8h.html#ab7284c43106d782296b584ab6adae2c3